# c++ iterator error

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a problem with iterator. Could you explain me why this code:

```
vector<vector<int> >::iterator it = v.begin();
for(; it < v.end(); it++)
{
  vector<int> var = *it;
  sort(var.begin(), var.end() );
}
```

is ok and with this code:

```
vector<vector<int> >::iterator it = v.begin();
for(; it < v.end(); it++)
{
  sort(*it.begin(), *it.end() );
}
```

is wrong? Compiler said that *it has no member begin, but I don;t know why.

Comment: Also note that your first loop has no outside effect - you're copying the vector into a local, sorting it, then it gets discarded. You should declare `var` as a non-const reference.

Comment: I have checked and it works (with reference). Thanks. One more question. I can't use const reference, because iterator is a non-const pointer? When I tried to make `const_iterator`, it didn't compile. Maybe when sort method is  changing elements, variable `var` should point to another element that is on the beginning of the vector (and therefore it can't be const)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Operator precedence.

`*it.begin()` is the same as `*(it.begin())`.  You need `(*it).begin()` (or the equivalent expression, `it->begin()`).

That is, you need to "call the member function `begin()` of the object pointed to by `it`," not "deference the result of calling the member function `begin()` on `it`" (`it` has no member function `begin()`, which is why the compiler gives you the error message that you get).

Answer (score 4):

The operator "." binds stronger than the operator "*". Try

```
vector<vector<int> >::iterator it = v.begin();
for(; it < v.end(); it++){
   sort(it->begin(), it->end() );
}
```

instead.

Your code works like this:

```
vector<vector<int> >::iterator it = v.begin();
for(; it < v.end(); it++)
{
  sort(*(it.begin()), *(it.end()) );
}
```

and `it` simply has no member `begin` as `it` is a simple iterator.